# How to write three billions records in parquet format efficient way

Tags: arrays, json, azure, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a sample dataset which have nested json for parameter section. Below is my pyspark code.

```
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column
from pyspark.sql.types import _parse_datatype_json_string
dfBomservices=spark.read.option("multiline","true").json('/mnt/fulldatabases/GES/20230411_1259256901_13_Bome_8f77ad0e-7313-481e-b9d7-baad344fd.json')
dfBomtransform=testFlatten().flattenAndExplode(dfBomservices)
dfBomtransform.write.format('parquet').save('/mnt/fulldatabases/GES/serv')
#display(dfBomtransform)
```

I have function flattenAndExplode which will do the explode and parsing but when I trying to write 3 billion record I face heartbeat error. Size of json is just 500KB. what is the best efficient  way to write in parquet format?

[image]

sample data:

[image]

Comment: Hello James sure I changed subject.

Comment: I again checked my dataframe counts (three billion three hundred eighty-five million nine hundred eighty-nine thousand seven hundred fifty)